# How can I get celery worker to only require broker_read_url

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#broker-read-url-broker-write-url

When I specify only the broker_read_url in `celeryconfig.py`, for some reason celery falls back to the default `amqp://localhost:5672`

This doesn't make sense to me. Why would a worker *need* to write to the broker? Looking at the source code, I can't see anything besides the purge option which would require it.

Is there a way around this? I've tried putting in a dummy url, and that doesn't work.

edit:
More details about my setup. I've got a rmq shovel set up, which I'm writing to, and a rmq instance I'm reading from. In my producer app, I want to configure only broker_read_url, and in the consuming worker, I want to only configure broker_write_url.

Since I can't do this, my assumption is that celery must be using it for something, but I can't really tell what looking through the code.

Comment: I never used this feature, so can't help much. However, did you try `broker_write_url = None` in your config?

Comment: Yes. Same result of default being used.